# How to monitor communication and health of RabbitMq endpoints via Application Insights?

Tags: rabbitmq, azure-application-insights

It is clear how to do monitoring for NServiceBus endpoints as [documented here](https://docs.particular.net/samples/logging/application-insights/).

For my current project, I need to know how to do this for RabbitMq with Azure Application Insights.